# passing paramaters from landing page to another

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

I would like to pass field parameter from one landing page to another. Then once it is passed, I can click submit bottom form.

Currently, I have created two landing pages for two data extensions. Both DEs have relationship campagins_ID.

When I enter the info using forms for the first DE then send it to landing page that will insert the data into DE there is a url in the bottom that says click here to fill up the landing page. When they click on that I want to pass the campaign_ID to the second form.

How would I be able to pass that information from Landing Page one to the URL in link at the bottom (Landing Page form 2).

Comment: you need to provide more insight into exactly what you want to do as well as provide some samples of what you have done already otherwise, this question will likely be closed.

Comment: What I need to do is I have created two landing pages for two data extensions. Both DEs have relationship campagins_ID. When the I enter the info using forms for the first DE then send it to landing page that will insert the data into DE there is a url in the bottom that says click here to fill up the landing page. When they click on that I want to pass the campaign_ID to the second form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is to add in parameters ([Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)) to your link.

example:

`http://www.yourlink.com/lp2?cuid=%%campaigns_ID%%`

After that you will need to add the ampscript '[Request Parameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm)' function onto LP 2 which will grab this parameter and store it in an ampscript variable.  From there you just place the variable into the 'value' attribute of your input and it is now successfully passed.

example:

```
    %%[ 
       Set @campaign_ID = RequestParameter("cuid") /* parameter name inside link above (on LP 1) */

    ]%%


<input name="myInput" value="%%=v(@campaign_ID)=%%">
```

Comment: Is it QueryParameter or RequestParameter

Comment: I use RequestParameter mostly because QueryParameter won't work for POST - so rather than potentially rewrite the code, I use Request for all.